# PDF Digital Signing : Change Date Format of Sign Date in Appearance

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I have successfully implement Digital PDF Signing by using iTexhSharp.dll (5.5.9), but I want to change the date format of Signing Date which is currently showing in '2016/10/01 00:00:00 +05'30'' this format and want to change in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS. Kindly help me.

My Code :

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
 //appearance.Reason = SignReason;
 //appearance.Location = SignLocation;
 appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
 appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(xPos, yPos, xPos + 200, yPos + 100), PageNo, "Signature1");//.IsInvisible

// Custom text and background image
appearance.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(SignatureImg);
appearance.ImageScale = 0.6f;
appearance.Image.Alignment = 300;
appearance.Acro6Layers = true;

//digital signature
IExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256");
MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, es, new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { pk12.GetCertificate(alias).Certificate }, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    stamper.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text used in the signature visualization using the `PdfSignatureAppearance` property `Layer2Text`:

```
appearance.Layer2Text = "...";
```

By default iTextSharp creates this text like this

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.Append("Digitally signed by ");
String name = null;
CertificateInfo.X509Name x500name = CertificateInfo.GetSubjectFields((X509Certificate)signCertificate);
if (x500name != null) {
    name = x500name.GetField("CN");
    if (name == null)
        name = x500name.GetField("E");
}
if (name == null)
    name = "";
buf.Append(name).Append('\n');
buf.Append("Date: ").Append(signDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss zzz"));
if (reason != null)
    buf.Append('\n').Append(reasonCaption).Append(reason);
if (location != null)
    buf.Append('\n').Append(locationCaption).Append(location);
text = buf.ToString();
```

in `PdfSignatureAppearance.GetAppearance()`. You can take this as a template for your `Layer2Text` creation code. (Obviously you will have to replace access to `PdfSignatureAppearance` members appropriately.) In particular you see the date format string and can change it accordingly.